# Prevent firefox from updating

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, firefox-16

I'm writing some python tests using `selenium 2.25.0` and the Firefox webdriver.

I previously had **Firefox version 16** (which worked just perfectly), but now it automatically updated itself to version 18, which is causing a lot of problems with my version of selenium and I want Firefox to prevent from updating if I haven't approved so.

I've found that the linux version of Firefox doesn't come with the option in *Preferences > Advanced > Update tab* to tell it to ask me what to do when a new version is available.

I've tried with `selenium==2.26`.0 and it kinda works for me locally, but unfortunately updating the version of selenium is no a suitable option since these tests have a while in production.

**I already have [Firefox 16 binaries](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/16.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/) and I need it to stay in such version**.

**Is there any way to accomplish this under Ubuntu 12.04?**

Thanks in advance for any help? :)

*P.D.* I don't care for any add-ons incompatibility, I don't need them so it's ok that some add-ons are not available after solving this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use about:config to set app.update.enabled and app.update.auto to False.

Answer (score 0):

Here are more detailed instructions as more people are not experts in Firefox configuration.

1. Open FireFox
2. In the address bar, type `about:config` and press Return
3. It will warn you, click I Accept the Risk
4. Search for app.update.enabled in the search bar the pops up
5. Double click it to flip the setting to false
6. Do the same thing for `app.update.auto`

I can verify this works.